# How to Apply Custom Filter to Camera & Photo View in Img.ly iOS SDK? XCode 8.1 Swift 3.0.1

Tags: ios, sdk

XCode 8.1 Swift 3.0.1

I've been playing with img.ly iOS SDK for the last few days and I'm really excited about it, especially, the full blown customization that they've offered.

Unfortunately, I'm facing a few issues which I seem to can't get my head around it.

I wanted to limit the filter effects for the user to use only 5 of them. I can make it work by using this code:

[image]

However, when I select a filter effect, the image won't apply that effect to the Camera view, like the picture below:

[image]

I've tried to hook up the filterToolControllerBuilder to the CameraViewController like below:

[image]

And I called the filterSelectedClosure to get the identifier, and I can get it. as the filter is selected like the image below:

[image]

Questions are in the picture.

1. How to apply the filter identifier to the photo?
2. How to get the filter identifier when filter in Camera View is selected?
3. How to apply that selected filter identifier to the live Camera preview?

It seems like this is the first question related to Img.ly iOS SDK.

Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this framework... let try to follow my code .

```
builder.configureAdjustToolController({ (options) in
                options.allowedAdjustTools = [.brightness]
                options.adjustToolButtonConfigurationClosure = { cell , action in
                    cell.imageView.image =  cell.imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                    cell.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.white

                }

            })
```